# How can I add a custom folder icon in vscode-icons?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been using the vscode-icons extenstion in VSCode and I wanted to add the VueJS logo for any folder named 'vue', 'vue-dev', and maybe more in the future. I have not found a clear tutorial with Google. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a very detailed step-by-step guide](https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/wiki/Custom) to use custom icons with that extension.